# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [range of positive mantissa in given floating-point number representation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8399/range-of-positive-mantissa-in-given-floating-point-number-representation)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Applying Dirichlet boundary conditions to the Poisson equation with finite volume method](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/applying-dirichlet-boundary-conditions-to-the-poisson-equation-with-finite-volum)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Computing $\sin(\pi/2)$ numerically](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8376/computing-sin-pi-2-numerically)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Binary vs. ASCII file size](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8404/binary-vs-ascii-file-size)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Computational complexity and implementation of UDU Modified Cholesky Rank 1 Update](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/computational-complexity-and-implementation-of-udu-modified-cholesky-rank-1-upda)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [approximating normal derivative of a continuous function with shape functions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/approximating-normal-derivative-of-a-continuous-function-with-shape-functions)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [VTK file format to image file](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8367/vtk-file-format-to-image-file)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Computational science contests. Why arent there any?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/computational-science-contests-why-arent-there-any)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Confusion regarding the Adam-Moulton and Backwards Differentiation Formula (BDF) of the VODE solver](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/confusion-regarding-the-adam-moulton-and-backwards-differentiation-formula-bdf)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Unknown domain in optimization problem](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/unknown-domain-in-optimization-problem)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the most interesting site evaluations I've participated in.  The quality of Answers (and Questions) surprised me, even though I'm enthusiastic about the site, because a majority of posts rewarded my reading with tidbits and nuggets that were informative.  I skipped one item as outside my competence, and pegged a couple of items as Satisfactory on the grounds that they contain more or less what I'd expect to find from a Google Search.  But a decided majority of items were reviewed as Excellent.

While I enjoyed posts by some of our prolific and articulate members, it was a chance to hear some views by contributors I'd not noticed before.

It was a bit of a letdown to come to the end of the Review Queue, not my usual response to these exercises.